# Emptying an ArrayList of LinkedList back into an Array

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I am trying to remove elements of an ArrayList of LinkedLists back into an Array. I am getting caught on a element not found exception.

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> stacks = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>(3);
int[] arr = new arr[5];

stacks.get(0).add(22);
stacks.get(0).add(1);
stacks.get(0).add(7);
stacks.get(1).add(111);
stacks.get(2).add(123);

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
   while (!stacks.isEmpty())
   {
      arr[i++] = stacks.get(i).remove();
   }
}
```

I would operate under the assumption that the while is NOT empty would account for this. I am curious why it will not successfully copy the contents over?

Comment: What do you mean by empty into an array?

Comment: input them into the array. So take the stacks.get(0) and stacks.get(1) and stacks.get(2)'s elements and input them into the array arr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

```
int[] arr = new int[5];   // not new arr[]
```

You are not adding a `LinkedList` to the `ArrayList`. You need to add `LinkedList`s first and then add items to `stacks`.

Your loop is completely wrong, I've rewritten it.

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> stacks = new ArrayList<>(3);
int[] arr = new int[5];

stacks.add(new LinkedList<>());
stacks.add(new LinkedList<>());
stacks.add(new LinkedList<>());

stacks.get(0).add(22);
stacks.get(0).add(1);
stacks.get(0).add(7);
stacks.get(1).add(111);
stacks.get(2).add(123);

int count = 0;
for (LinkedList<Integer> stack : stacks) {
    for (Integer integer : stack) {
        arr[count++] = integer;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.  This example uses `ArrayLists` but it will also work with `LinkedLists` or anything that implements the `List` interface.

Create the list of lists.

```
        ArrayList<List<Integer>> stacks =
                new ArrayList<>(List.of(List.of(22, 1, 7),
                        List.of(111, 112), List.of(44, 123, 99)));
```

And convert to `int array`

```
int[] ints = stacks
        .stream()                   // convert to a stream of lists
        .flatMap(List::stream)      // combine all lists to one list of Integers
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)// convert Integers to ints
        .toArray();                 // and output to an array.

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
```

Prints

```
[22, 1, 7, 111, 112, 44, 123, 99]
```